# Python regex replace list of pattern

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a list of patterns:

```
patterns = ["how", "do you do", "are you doing", "goes it"]
```

Any occurrences of list's items in string should be replaced to **"how are you"**.

*For example:*

String **"how do you do?"** should be replaced to **"how are you?"**

*What I use:*

```
s = input()  
for pattern in patterns:
       s = re.sub(rf"(\b{pattern}\b)", "how are you", s)
```

The problem is that I receive **"how are you how are you"**.

The easiest solution is to change list of patterns to:

```
patterns = ["how do you do", "how are you doing", "how goes it"]
```

*****But I need to keep "how" in list and keep it separately from other items.*****

Comment: You may want to replace the pattern: `how` + either item of the list
`["do you do", "are you doing", "goes it"]` with `how are you`, correct?

Comment: This is not clear, what are you trying to achieve? Look, you either want to 1) analyze the keywords, find overlapping ones (or only those starting with `how`) and append negative lookaheads to shorter variants (which is not really a good idea, it is too cumbersome), 2) replace one or more whitespace separated keyword occurrences (but what do you need to get in case of `how goes it` or `how are you doing`? You only mention `do you do`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

patterns = ["how", "do you do", "are you doing", "goes it"]
first = patterns.pop(0)                 # pop the 1st element
pattern = rf"\b{first}\s+(?:" + "|".join(patterns) + r")\b"
# pattern equals to r"\bhow\s+(?:do you do|are you doing|goes it)\b"
s = input()
s = re.sub(pattern, "how are you", s)
print(s)
```

If you prefer to using a loop, here is an alternative:

```
import re

patterns = ["how", "do you do", "are you doing", "goes it"]
first = patterns.pop(0)                 # pop the 1st element
s = input()
for pattern in patterns:
    s = re.sub(rf"\b{first}\s+{pattern}\b", "how are you", s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with the `s` inside and outside the `re.sub`, this overwrite the `input()`
Use another varialbe, like `m`

```
s = input()  
for pattern in patterns:
    m = re.sub(rf"(\b{pattern}\b)", "how are you", s)
```